# io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step "User is in login page" is undefined. You can implement it using the snippet(s) below:

Tags: selenium, cucumber, feature-selection, cucumber-java

I have the following error:
[image]
but I have implemented the steps
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

How I can do?

Answer (score 1):

This means that Cucumber cannot find your step definition, because it is in a different place than Cucumber is looking for it (either by default, or where you specified it to look).

From the [Cucumber FAQ](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/):

"**Cucumber says my steps are undefined, but I have implemented step definitions!**

If Cucumber is telling you that your steps are undefined, when you have defined step definitions, this means that Cucumber cannot find your step definitions. You’ll need to make sure to specify the path to your step definitions (glue path) correctly.

By default Cucumber-JVM will search in the package (or sub-packages) of the runner class. You can also tell Cucumber-JVM explicitly which packages (and sub-packages) to search, with:

```
 @CucumberOptions(glue = {"<package>", "<package>", "<etc>"})
 public class RunCucumberTest{}
```

"

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and cleaned the project and update maven then issue got fixed .

Comment: great, but this could be a comment instead of an answer :) welcome to stackoverflow! please have a look at: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment